# how to avoid emacs' replacing quotation marks in French

Tags: emacs, latex, quoting, babeljs

When you use babel with French (set by, `\usepackage[francais]{babel}` emacs replaces automatically quotations marks (") by \og and \fg (you need only to restart emacs after adding babel).

It could be quite cool. But I'm using csquotes package which allows to have the good quotation marks by simply writing ".

```
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
```

So this amazing feature of emacs (the automatic replacement of " by \og or \fg) is useless for me and even painful.

How do I remove it?

It seems it is the font-latex-quotes variable which manage this. But options are only French (<< >>) or German (>> <<). I would like to redefine this variable to consider "test" as quote with test in color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by modifying the variables `LaTeX-csquotes-open-quote` and `LaTeX-csquotes-close-quote`.

I define the first variable as `\enquote{` and the second as `}`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using auctex. you need to customize the value of variable `TeX-quote-language` to 'override.

This special value makes that language-related styles inhibit to modify its value, so quoting magic is deactivated.

Comment: I don't find your variable (and I use csquote).